# Android Studio 4.0.0 - Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

from a week I was updated my Android Studio version to stable version 4.0.0 then I am started getting this errors in my studio and unable to build the app.

Unable to save plugin settings: The plugin org.jetbrains.android failed to save settings and has been disabled. Please restart Android Studio
But I forcefully enabled all plugins in my Studio by going to File-->Settings-->Plugins --> All are enabled.

Comment: Go to File--> Project Structure --> Check Use Embedded JDK (Recommended)

Comment: try deleting .idea folder as well

Comment: in android 4.0.0 I'm not found Check Use Embedded JDK (Recommended) !! 
@DirkDeWinnaar

Comment: File--> Project Structure --> SDK Location --> Dropdown JDK Location :Select Embeded JDK

Answer (score 3):

Try that:
delete the .idea folder in the android project folder where you faced this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Select Embedded JDK in Android Studio
[image: Embedded JDK to Select]

Comment: didn't solve the problem. it still showed unable to save settings error. had to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio. Now navigate to your projects .idea folder and rename the workspace.xml file to workspace-o.xml and delete a workspace.xml~ if it exists (i.e., AS has a corrupt workspace layout file).

This should fix the problem. Restart AS and configure the workspace back they way you like it (i.e., it will start with a simple view: View/Tools Windows/Project etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I started my first project in Android Studio and my answer may not be the correct one. I ran into this problem during building the My Activity project. It always came back with this error asking me to restart. Finally I thought that the controlled folder file access is preventing me. I temporarily switched-off the protection(against Ransomware in Windows 10) and tried the Build. I stopped getting these messages. But, I have other problems I am looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .idea folder and then I invalidated the cache (file-> invalidate Cache/Restart)
This fixed my issue.